# Delete answer to Facebook question?

Tags: facebook, facebook-questions

How can I delete an answer to a question on Facebook?

Note that I don't want to *hide* it but to ***delete*** it.

> WhoAmI answered Someone's question.
>
> ---
>
> Question content
>
> - `[ x ]` Answer 1 `[ ME ] [O] [T] [H] [E] [R] [S]`
> - `[   ]` Answer 2
> - `[   ]` Answer 3

Example:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting how they introduced the *Unvote* option (it **was NOT existing when I posted the question**).

Go to `https://www.facebook.com/<yourusername>/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_105` (replace `<yourusername>` with your username) and click the buttons like in the following screenshot:

> [image]

The `Unvote` option will remove the answer to a Facebook question.

Then the page where you answered the question (`https://www.facebook.com/<yourusername>/posts/<postid>`) will appear like this:

> [image]